# Neumann initial-boundary value problem for parabolic equation

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, parabolic-pde

Do we have some textbooks introducing the basic stuff in this topic? Such as existence, regularity and maximum principle?

I have found some standard text such as Gary Lieberman, but I do not have any result. Thank you so much!

Comment: Finally get some results from Section 2 and 3 in the book "Nonlinear Parabolic
and Elliptic Equations" by C.V. Pao.

Comment: Also Chapter 2.5 and 5 in the book "Partial Differential Equations of Parabolic Type" by  Avner Friedman.